# A cross platform function to get current time in seconds with precision of micro second

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime

```
double time_in_seconds() {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::microseconds> tp = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    auto tmp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch());
    std::time_t time_micro = tmp.count();
    return time_micro / 1000000.0;
}
```

Here C++11 `chrono` is used to be able run on multi platform. Use `high_resolution_clock` to hope to get precision of micro second. `std::time_t` should be enough to hold this number.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  You might get better reviews if you show a little more of the context, such as a sample `main` that shows how you intend to use this function.

Comment: Very few computing devices can achieve an absolute time accuracy of a few microseconds. Such precision might be useful within a single device, but this is supposed to be cross-platform. How can such precise time values on different devices be useful?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with clang 8, but does with gcc 9. I suspect cross-compiler is necessary to achieve cross-platform ;-) (btw the cause is an impossible conversion from `stdeady_clock` to `system_clock`)

Answer (score 3):

Leveraging the standard library is the best way to obtain cross-platform code, so you're on the right track. The problem is that your doesn't compile with one of the compilers I've tested it with (clang 8). Using auto would make your code simpler and avoid problematic conversions:

```
double time_in_seconds() {
    // now compiles with both clang 8 and gcc 9
    auto tp = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    auto tmp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch());
    auto time_micro = tmp.count();
    return time_micro / 1000000.0;
}
```

Besides, there is no need for those intermediary, ill-named variables `tp` and `tmp`. If your function is contained in an implementation file (`.cpp`), where it should be, importing the `std::chrono` namespace is perfectly fine, and it becomes quite readable:

```
double time_in_seconds() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() / 1000000.0;
}
```

`auto` would also be a better choice for the return type:

```
auto time_in_seconds() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()
           / 1000000.0l; // long double literal
}
```

`auto` here avoids any discrepancy between the promotion done in the arithmetic operation (the division by 1.000.000) and the promotion to the return type. For instance:

```
long double foo() { // seemingly long double precision
    return some_integer / 100.01f; // actually float precision
}
```

A last improvement I think of is the use of enhanced literals:

```
auto time_in_seconds() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() 
           / 1'000'000.0l; // you can separate thousands with '
}
```

Comment: I recommend `L` for the "long" suffix - `.0l` looks a lot like `.01` at first reading...  And consider scientific notation for a power of 10 - perhaps subjective, but I find `1e6L` easier than counting zeros.